# looking for a wysiwyg editor with some particular features

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Not entirely sure if something like this exists or not. If it does, im at a loss as to what to search for to find it.

- I need an inpage/inline (jquery?) wysiwyg editor with templating, so i can load in a basic (preferably uneditable) layout, that the user then fills in.
- Image uploading and gallery. So a user can either upload a picture, or insert one from a selection within a gallery.
- Ability to convert the contents for storage and retrieval in db (if its all text/html), or even better a way to save the entirety as a flattened image.

I know this is a tall order, but ive seen the individual pieces in different editors, but not all in one. Perhaps im searching for the wrong thing, but any help here would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently used [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and as far as I can see it it is capable of doing everything you need:

- **Templating**: No problem, see [Templating](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Templates)
- **Image Uploading**: Possible. It's described [here](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_%28Uploader%29). Though they use an own (not free)  file manager AFAIR. But writing a simple file browser with jquery isn't really a hard task (see [jQuery file tree](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/customizable-ajax-file-browser-for-jquery/) as a simple example). You just need to integrate it with the ckeditor file upload dialog (but all this is described in the docs quite well). Of course you can also spend some money in order to use their file manager and don't worry about integrating your own.
- **Storage**: CKEditor creates pure HTML markup. I don't know why there should be a problem storing this markup in your database of choice.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, im going to check this out and see what i can come up with.